# How to use proxy authentication with Goutte?

Tags: php, guzzle, goutte

I have the following code but it always returns a `407` HTTP status code.

```
$url = 'http://whatismyip.org';

$client = new Client();

$options = array(
    'proxy' => array(
        'http'  => 'tcp://@x.x.x.x:8010',
    ),
    'auth' => array('d80fe9ebasab73d21a4', '', 'basic')
);

$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url, $options);

$status = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();

echo $status; // 407
```

I am using Goutte with Guzzle 6. I started off trying to set the proxy with `setDefaultOption` but this method has been deprecated.

My username and blank password is definitely correct as it works with `curl` on the command line:

```
curl -U d80fe9ebasab73d21a4: -vx x.x.x.x:8010 http://whatismyip.org/
```

I have spent several hours on this and I would appreciate any help!

Comment: This may happen when a client tries to use HTTP1 instead of HTTP1.1
 --  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1); Not sure how the client works on the inside .. check your curl version

Comment: Hard to say. Use Wireshark to inspect request on network layer. Also check that you have enabled cURL extension in your PHP and Guzzle uses CurlHandler. Why do you have `@` char before proxy IP? You can also try as proxy address something like this `http://d80fe9ebasab73d21a4@x.x.x.x:8010` and omit `auth` option.

Comment: @Abs : How did you solve proxy issue . can you let me know ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to instantiate your Client with the proxy options directly?

Like this:

```
$url = 'http://whatismyip.org';

$client = new Client($url, array(
    'version'        => 'v1.1',
    'request.options' => array(
        'auth'    => array('d80fe9ebasab73d21a4', '', 'Basic'),
        'proxy'   => 'tcp://@x.x.x.x:8010'
    )
));


$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);

$status = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();

echo $status; // 407
```

Comment: Stucken : This solution is not working for me . its returning the my local system ip instead of proxy IP . can you suggest some solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$config = [
    'proxy' => [
        'http' => 'xx.xx.xx.xx:8080'
    ]
];

$client = new Client($config);
$client->setAuth('username', 'password', 'basic');

$crawler = $client->request('GET', $url);
$status = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();

echo $status;
```

I suppose it's a client configuration, not a request parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In new version you should use like this.

```
$config = ['proxy' => host:port];

$client = new Client(HttpClient::create($config));
```

Remember to mentions

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;
use Goutte\Client;
```

Basically a client configuration needed.